# Last moment of zoom in effect,Image stay for while on screen in android

Tags: android

I have applied zoom in effect to an image,
And last moment of zoom in effect,
image should be stay for while on screen (like 50 seconds on screen).
To keep stay image on screen what can i do .??

I have applied below zoom_in animation on image.

**zoom_in.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <scale
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromXScale="0.8"
            android:fromYScale="0.8"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toXScale="1.5"
            android:toYScale="1.5" >
        </scale>

    </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done with Timer,I have set duration between start animation and next statement.So in between time image will stay on screen for this time.